# Seeding not passing validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have churches but churches have a foreign table schedules when they are opened.

```
churches_list.each do |name, street, city, zip, country, description|
  church = Church.new(name: name,
              street: street, 
              city: city, 
              zip: zip, 
              country: country, 
              description: description)

  Schedule.create!(start_date: Date.today+7, 
                   start_hour: t, 
                   end_hour: t+8, 
                   church_id: church.id, 
                   schedule_type: "oneDay")
  church.save
```

But when I run the seeds it just states: "church requires at least one schedule"

So I think my church.schedules are not attaching correctly for some reason.

Comment: `church = Church.new` - it just instantiate the `church` object but you never saved it. You should save it before trying to `create!` `Schedule`.

Comment: The error remained, saving the creation of the schedule to a variable, removing the ID from the save and afterwards linking it to the Vacancy seemed to work, Thank you for trying to help me, it set me on the right path to this solution.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the ID from Schedule.create and saving the created schedule to a variable (ex schedule) and then doing

```
church.schedules = [schedule]
```

before church.save fixed the issue. I guess letting ActiveRecord linking the two together instead of forcing an ID in the creation of schedule fixed it.